# os.walk help - processing data in chunks - python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv, os.walk

I have some files that are scattered in many different folders within a directory, and I was wondering if there were a way to iterate through these folders in chunks.

[Here's a picture of my directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xewS8.jpg)

I'd want to go through all the files in my 2010A folder, then 2010B folder, then move to 2011A and 2011B etc..

My goal is to amend my current script, which only works for a single folder, so that it flows like this:

**Start**: ROOT FOLDER >

- 2010 > 2010A >
- output to csv> **re-start loop** >
- 2010B > append csv after the last row
- re-start loop > 2011 > 2011A >
- append csv after the last row > and so on...

Is this possible?

Here's my code, it currently works if I run it on a single folder containing my txt files, e.g., for the 2010A folder:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
from collections import Counter
#get file list in current directory
filelist = os.listdir(r'root_folder\2010\2010A')
dict1 = {}

#open and read files, store into dictionary
for file in filelist:
    with open(file) as f:
        items = f.read()
    dict1[file] = items

#create filter for specific words
filter = [ "cat", "dog", "elephant", "fowl"]

dict2 = {}
# count occurrence of words in each file
for k, v in dict1.items():
        list= []
        for i in filter:
        list.extend(re.findall(r"{}".format(i),v))
        dict2[k] = dict(Counter(new))

dict3 ={}
# count total words in each file, store in separate dictionary
dict3 = {k: {'total':len(v)} for k,v in dict1.items()}

join_dict = {}
#join both dictionaries
join_dict = {k:{**dict2[k], **dict3[k]} for k in out}

#convert to pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(join_dict, orient='index').fillna(0).astype(int)

#output to csv
df.to_csv(r'path\output.csv',index = True, header=True)
```

I have a feeling I need to replace:

`for file in filelist:`

with `for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(r'root_folder', topdown=True):`

But I'm not exactly sure *how*, since I'm quite new to coding and python in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob` to get list of files like this

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('root_folder\\*.txt', recursive=True)
```

Comment: So, would I need to put this inside my for-loop? When I leave it outside, I just get an empty list for `files`. If I omit the `*.txt`, it returns the current directory, but that's all.